# Osgi maven bundle

Tags: maven, osgi, osgi-bundle, apache-servicemix

I m working on a big project, about 400 bundle with her own version.

We use maven to generate all artifact but as you k ow all bundle have different version, so we have defined in each bundle a version with a property like

```
<version>${my.bundle.version}</version>
```

And in the root parent pom.xml we have define all version properties.
It permit to have a delivery bundle that generate only a features.xml, and in the featurs.xml we can use same properties as defined in pom.xml

When we do a version we can change the pom.xml parent version. Example for version 1.0.0 all bundle are in 1.0.0 and in version 1.1.0 we have 200 bundles in 1.0.0 because no modification but 200 others bundle in 1.1.0 or 2.0.0 if major update and etc... after in servicemix we can add features:addurl 1.0.0 and next addurl 1.1.0 and again and again...

But i would like to know if we are right or If you have some others idea’s to maintain all bundle more efficacely or simply?

Thanks

Comment: The simplest solution is to keep a single version for all bundles and create a release over all modules/bundles using the same version and let for example tycho-versions-plugin set all the version in features.xml etc. makes it easier...

Comment: Yes but you create a release for all bundle even if you change only 1 bundle:( i know it s easier but not really good:(

Comment: We can discuss a long time about being good or not...it much easier..If you like to have different versions than you need to go the way to see the bundles as separate projects which have a different release cycle with all it's problems etc. If you have a single multi module builds it easier to handle..It's up to your how to go....

Comment: yes i understand your point of view, my question is just to know if other project have same problem and how they solve it (or not). It's Just to have different point of view and try to choose the best (if exist ;)) thanks for your proposal.